# Strange delayed painting with Qt5 on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I'm using Qt5 in Windows. I just created a simple little widgets project in Qt Creator. I have a `QMainWindow` with a text edit widget inside. I enabled vertical layout, so the text edit consumes the full size of the inside of the main window (which is what I want, I'm trying to create a small notepad app).

As I drag the bottom right corner of the main window during the preview (I click the green triangle in the bottom left) I'm seeing a slight delay in the child widget's resizing. It doesn't exactly resize with the parent window on the same render frame (it seems like it is 1-2 render frames behind).

I remember years ago dealing with render lag like this in old school Win32 API. I remember I had to do double-buffered rendering into an offscreen bitmap to fix it (or something along those lines; been a long time).

Is there a way to fix this "render lag" in Qt? I can only imagine this is specific to Windows and might not impact other platforms, although I have not tested. If I need to provide more information let me know.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I suggest compiling and running the "textedit" example app in $QTDIR/qtbase/examples/widgets/richtext/textedit and see if it also exhibits that same problem.  If so, it may just be an artifact of the way Qt is implemented under Windows; if not, see what the textedit example app is doing differently than your app.  (FWIW I don't see any lag when resizing under MacOS/X with Qt 5.3.1)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jeremy. I ran the sample and I'm indeed still seeing the issue.

Comment: Could you please include some code so ? So I could try it and maybe help you.

Comment: Interesting, I'm seeing the same thing.  Qt 5.4, VS2012, Windows 8.1.  I thought maybe it was a debug vs release kinda thing but saw the same effect in both.  This was compiling the textedit example project.  It does appear to be a tad bit behind (you can see the parent widget's blue background in the example project).

Comment: Just to add, I'm also noticing this on some other Windows applications like Chrome.

Comment: @void.pointer I would advice you to update your video drivers. I experienced lags like you describe - updating video drivers worked for me. Based on my Qt experience - such simple app like you work on should never give such lags. They usually appear when you try to customize non-client window area (e.g. to make firefox-like button in window header). So once again - this looks like system lag to me, not the Qt one. Try to launch your app on another PC/MAC.

Comment: @dalamber that's not the issue.

Comment: Qt already does double-buffering since 4.something, so this shouldn't be your issue.
I tried the TextEdit example in Qt 5.3.2 (recent graphics drivers) and the issue is more noticable in Debug than in Release mode, so I suspect the window does not get redrawn as often as it should. The TextEdit code should be fine, so I suggest you take a look at the [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel) and see if you can find an bug that resembles the behaviour.

Comment: Read this [Qt 5 on Windows ANGLE and OpenGL](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5_on_Windows_ANGLE_and_OpenGL)  maybe it can help figuring out the issue. There is something suspicious about how Qt renders it widgets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely a Windows problem, not Qt's. The more GUI-heavy your window is the more noticeable it is.

---

I investigated the same issue a while ago. We had a rather GUI-heavy window, with several widgets displaying 2D and 3D views of data. Resizing the window using lower-right corner resulted in a resize-redraw horror. Unfortunately it looks like the problem is not Qt related but rather the way that Windows handles redrawing a resized window. I was able to notice the problem even in the file explorer on Windows 7. Qt is indeed using double buffering by default (as mentioned in the comment by @Bim). I also tried explicitly triggering Qt's repaint events. This helped a little, but did not solve the problem. So after many efforts we just decided to live with it.

Comment: Just to add: "we just decided to live with it." that's probably the only sane way to handle this. Even Microsoft products like VS2015, Outlook, Explorer, etc show this behaviour, so MS just "lives with it", too.